# $(...).attr is not a function - JQuery on A tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I have a JQuery selector to select a specific a tag that points to a url

```
$( "a[href='/imdb/videos/10155754083343949/']")
```

The query returns this:

```
<a data-onclick="[[&quot;VideoChannelHandleLink&quot;,&quot;handleClick&quot;]]" class="async_saving _5pcq" href="/imdb/videos/10155754083343949/" aria-label="Wonder Woman 2 Release Date" data-video-id="10155754083343949" data-video-channel-id="387437888106301:10155754083343949" data-channel-caller="channel_view_from_unknown" ajaxify="/imdb/videos/vb.15925638948/10155754083343949/?type=3" rel="async" target=""><abbr title="Wednesday, July 26, 2017 at 10:42am" data-utime="1501045936" data-shorten="1" class="_5ptz"><span class="timestampContent" id="js_1g">Yesterday at 10:42am</span></abbr></a>
```

I want to access the `aria-label` attribute of this Tag using
`$( "a[href='/imdb/videos/10155754083343949/']").attr("aria-label")`
But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr is not a function
at <anonymous>:1:49
```

Thanks in Advance.

UPDATE:
It's solved now. $ was not referring to JQuery It was just the shortcut for querySelector in chrome console. Due to some other reason, JQuery was not properly injected. Fixed it now!

Comment: Your code should work fine. Are you sure `$` is a reference to jQuery?

Comment: I think it is else the select should not work should it? and I can do `$( "a[href='/imdb/videos/10155754083343949/']").href`. It works

Comment: I tried that too I don't think I get an array. The result is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:51`

Comment: sounds like you do not have jQuery, sounds like you are using the console and you have Chrome's shortcut for querySelector and not jQuery.

Comment: When you are sure that jQuery is loaded, try with "jQuery" instead of "$" and tell me the result. If it works then you have a conflict with another library or object.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I just did `jQuery( "a[href='/imdb/videos/10155754083343949/']").attr("aria-label")` and got 
`"Wonder Woman 2 Release Date"`. I did not knew chrome had a shortcut for that. I had an extension to inject jquery and I forgot to choose it on top of the console. I'm sure the issue is solved. Thank you